# Magit, an easy way to see if there is more than one line of comments in Magit-Status

Tags: magit

To clarify I know about `magit-revision` i.e. spacebar but there doesn't seem to be a clear way to tell if a commit has more than one line of comments or not.

What I'm talking about is this:

`be93ed0 master origin/master Changed the code for foo.`

But then if you press spacebar you can see more of the message:

```
be93ed0 master origin/master Changed the code for foo.

Changed it from bar to foo because of such and such.
```

Ideally I would like to hit "tab" and the message would expand, but I'm willing to settle for something that just indicates there is more then one line of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on `-h` ("Show header (++header)") from `*magit-log-popup*`, it will display commit message's body, author and committer. See also the user option `magit-log-revision-headers-format`.